# Python: ValueError (CSV row has different number of fields) with CSV and Tensorflow

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, dataset

this is my first question.

I´m working on a program, that predicts a number of people in a room. I got a CSV-file with data for this. The CSV has 6 columns and 96 rows (including header).
But when I run the program, this error occurs:

**ValueError: Problem inferring types: CSV row has different number of fields than expected.**

The Code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import functools

import tensorflow as tf

import xlrd

import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

train_data_url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/mug8rjlniftu065/train_data_csv.csv?dl=0"

test_data_url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/std8rt6lezl79ti/test_data_csv.csv?dl=0"

train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("training_data_csv.csv", train_data_url)
test_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("test_data_csv.csv", test_data_url)

np.set_printoptions(precision = 3, suppress=True)

#!head {train_file_path}

Label_Column = 'Besucher'
Labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]

def get_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):

    dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
        file_path,
        batch_size=96,
        label_name = Label_Column,
        na_value="?",
        num_epochs = 1,
        ignore_errors=True,
        **kwargs
    )
    return dataset
```

Please ignore the "Labels"-variable. Normally, the value of my prediction can be anything between 0 and 900, I didn´t figure out so far how to display this properly.

Does anyone know, what this error means? I wasn´t able to find this exact same error again. As far as I can see, all my Csv-files have the exact same number of fileds per row in each row.

Kind regards and thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you download the csv from that link and then try reading with `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset`?

Comment: Downloading is no problem, but how do I read the csv with this function? As far as I know has make_csv_dataset no parameter to use the file from the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doch, you can just put the name of the csv file in this function.

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset('filename_for_datasetCSV.csv', batch_size = 1, select_columns = ['short_description','Label'], label_name = 'Label', num_epochs = 1 ,shuffle = True
```

Use this above function after replacing the names of the columns and filename.

Comment: I found my mistake. With the function I used, I wrote "file_path" instead of "train_file_path". I understood with your code. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed that too, but I thought you are aware of it and pasted a sample code here. Silly mistakes happen.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I follow the instructions given here: [tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv] A few lines later, I get the exact same error-line, but for a different function: `raw_train_data = get_dataset(train_file_path)`
Could you help me with this as well?

Comment: Could you replace `get_dataset` function with the code I wrote above? Make sure to write the column names correctly i.e. how they are in the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check your csv file to check which line as the issue. Because it can be a blank line at the end of the file or a missing comma or so many others things...

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'r') as f1:
    csvlines = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
    for lineNum, line in enumerate(csvlines):
        if not len(line)==6:
            print(f"line:{lineNum} \t length:{len(line)}")
```